# Subtract an array of complex objects from another array of same kind of objects ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, nsarray

I know that subtracting an NSArray from NSArray if it is a single basic object [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341767/subtracting-arrays)

But what i have is an object like this

```
@interface Set : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *ItemId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *time;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Category_id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *List_id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@end
```

How can i delete an array having the set object from another array with the same?
It can be done by iterations that i knw.Is there some other way ?

EDIT: For clarity

I have **Array A** with 5 Set objects and  I have 4 Set Objects in **Array B**
array A and Array B contain 3 set objects with common values..[**Note : memory may be different**] common

All I need is an **Array C =Array A - Array B** that has 2 objects in resulting array C

Thank You :)

Comment: [Remove duplicate objects from an NSMutableArray](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6518714/1603234) and check *micpringle* answer.

Comment: Checked it says that it is about removing duplicate by comparing and itrating in a loop...I knew that way.Is there some other method?

Comment: let me understand... You have 2 arrays arr1 and arr2, both having objects of `Set`. You want to find `resultArr=arr1-arr2`. is it?

Comment: Please post your both NSArray with set objects.

Comment: @Bhargavi : Its just 2 NSArray with the Set Objects

Comment: @LithuT.V, Check my answer. It does the same thing. But note that under the hood it will be still enumerating objects. You cant avoid that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement the `- (NSUInteger)hash` and `- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object` method in `Set` class.

For eg:-

```
- (NSUInteger)hash {
   return [self.ItemId hash];
}

- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object
{
    return ([object isKindOfClass:[self class]] &&
            [[object ItemId] isEqual:_ItemId])

}
```

After that try this:

```
NSMutableSet *set1 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array1];
NSMutableSet *set2 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array2];
[set1 intersectSet:set2]; //this will give you only the obejcts that are in both sets

NSArray *commonItems = [set1 allObjects];

[mutableArray1 removeObjectsInArray:commonItems];//mutableArray1 is the mutable copy of array1
```

`mutableArray1` will have all objects in the same order as earlier after removing common objects.

Answer (score 1):

By using `NSSet` and `NSPredicate` we can meet your requirement.

```
Assessors *ass1 = [[Assessors alloc] init];
ass1.AssessorID = @"3";

Assessors *ass2 = [[Assessors alloc] init];
ass2.AssessorID = @"2";

Assessors *ass3 = [[Assessors alloc] init];
ass3.AssessorID = @"1";

Assessors *ass4 = [[Assessors alloc] init];
ass4.AssessorID = @"2";

NSSet *nsset1 = [NSSet setWithObjects:ass1, ass2,  nil];
NSSet *nsset2 = [NSSet setWithObjects:ass3, ass4, nil];

// retrieve the IDs of the objects in nsset2
NSSet *nsset2_ids = [nsset2 valueForKey:@"AssessorID"];

// only keep the objects of nsset1 whose 'id' are not in nsset2_ids
NSSet *nsset1_minus_nsset2 = [nsset1 filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT AssessorID IN %@",nsset2_ids]];

for(Assessors *a in nsset1_minus_nsset2)
    NSLog(@"Unique ID : %@",a.AssessorID);
```

Here Assessors is my NSObject Class (Set in your case) and AssessorID is one property of that class.

Hope this can help.